# Google Maps API Javascript API v2 returns "sensor" issue

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm getting this error message in my production box:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The "sensor" parameter specified in the request must be set to either "true" or "false".

When the browser hits:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=mykey&sensor=true">
```

I see that the browser calls upon:

> http:// maps . google . com 
>   /maps?file=api&v=2&key=mykey&sensor=true

And then it shows me the error message.

I copy the url it's hitting and paste it in the browser and it downloads the correct js, not the one with the alert message.

I created a sample page and tested it in my local dev box and my test server; it renders fantastic.
Test box: http://www.probit.co/Prototypes/GPS/MapTest.html

I placed the very same file in production box and it throws me the message.
Production box: http://www.hondutrack.com/rastreo/MapTest.html

Why wouldn't it work in Production?

Comment: You are mixing up `&amp;` and `&` in your URL. Change that and it'll likely work (I can see nothing else wrong)

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks for your response, I changed it using just `&amp;` or just `&`, sadly it didn't work. I was thinking, maybe the apache2 versions are different, so I deployed it to another server with the same apache2 version and it's working as expected -> [http://ch.sabuesotrack.com/MapTest.html](http://ch.sabuesotrack.com/MapTest.html)

Comment: Why are you attempting to use the deprecated [Google Maps API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?  It should not be used for _any_ new applications.

Comment: Hey @geocodezip, we must support this version until management gives us the green light to migrate. The thing is that the production stopped working out of the blue without any one login in or updating something.

Comment: The doctype is wrong, maybe it works when you fix it.

Comment: SUpport for Google Maps V2 was dropped May 19 this year. That's not why your map isn't working but FYI. The only other thing that I can see is that you are using XHTML, do you really want that?

Comment: I just grabbed the code straight out of the google api dev resources. I changed them to HTML4 strict and then HTML5 but that didn't seem to work. :(

Comment: I think you also need to remove the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` part

Comment: Thanks for your time @Pekka웃, I don't think it's the markup, I'm giving up on this. I thinking it's maybe the domain that's being blocked, my last move is to setup a new identical server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Even though the message showed some problem with the sensor parameter, I concluded that it was a domain issue, some kind of ban from the google map service.

Like it's detailed above, the very same html which renders the map was placed in three different domains, all of them working as expected but the production one. I used fiddler to see the request sent by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=mykey&sensor=true">
```

The original hit, returned the js with the error alert. I did a replay and changed the referer property in the http header with an invented and not existent domain (www.hondutrack1.com) and it worked liked a charm.

So to restore the service, we bought that domain, setup mod_rewrite in the apache server, created the rewrite in the root .htaccess file and everything is working now.

I know this is a workaround, kind of dirty, but at least the service is up and running.